# how to test edit route in CRUD application

Tags: flask

I have a route `/edit` with function `edit()` that edit or update user data, the URL when I click edit for a specefic user is like :

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/edit?id=60b7764170e26432acfa6bb2

how can I write a unittest for this route, I didn't know how to pass the id to the test

this is the route **/edit** with its function

```
@users.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit():

    id = request.args.get('id')
    user = User.objects.get_or_404(pk=id)
    form = UserForm(obj=user)




    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if user.update(username=form.username.data, firstname=form.firstname.data, 
        lastname=form.lastname.data, birthdate=form.birthdate.data, email=form.email.data, admin=form.admin.data, aktive=form.aktive.data):
            flash("user updated", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('.index'))
        else:
            flash("user couldn't be updated", "danger")
            return render_template('edit.html', user=user, form=form, info=session)

    return render_template('edit.html', user=user, form=form, info=session)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a test same as other test scripts, but here you have to use the requests module for making requests to edit route with certain parameters. Like

```
import requests
params = { "id" : "1234455" }
requests.get('http://localhost:Port/edit', params)
```

and you can specify port like this in the flask app

```
app.run(port=5000)
```

Let me know if it works. if not we will figure this out